# Pandas : remove all groups that does not contain into a col2 one element present in the list

Tags: python, pandas

Hel lo, I have a df such as :

```
col1 col2
G1 A
G1 B
G1 C
G1 D
G2 E
G2 F
G2 G
G3 H
G4 I
G4 J
G4 K
```

and a `liste=['A','I','K']`

and I would like to remove all groups that does not contain into the col2 one element present in the liste.

Here I should keep only `G1` and `G4` and get :

```
 col1 col2
    G1 A
    G1 B
    G1 C
    G1 D
    G4 I
    G4 J
    G4 K
```

Does someone have in idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using `isin`, `GroupBy.transform` and `any`

First we use `isin` to check which rows contain an element from your `liste`. Then we `GroupBy` on `col1` and check if `any` of the rows in a group contain an element of the list`

The reason we use `transform` here over simple `GroupBy.any` is because we want to get a vector back, with the same length as your dataframe, to do row wise comparison.

```
df[df['col2'].isin(liste).groupby(df['col1']).transform('any')]

   col1 col2
0    G1    A
1    G1    B
2    G1    C
3    G1    D
8    G4    I
9    G4    J
10   G4    K
```

Comment: You can also skip the assign (for large dataframes - probably worthwhile) if you change the grouping a little bit, eg: `df[df['col2'].isin(liste).groupby(df['col1']).transform('any')]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use groupby and apply:

```
df.groupby('col1').apply(lambda x: x if any(i in x['col2'].values for i in liste)
                                            else None).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

It gives:

```
   col1 col2
0    G1    A
1    G1    B
2    G1    C
3    G1    D
8    G4    I
9    G4    J
10   G4    K
```